# Conditional "step" for JQueryUI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to give conditional steps for JQuery UI Slider. If Current selected value is below 1951, take steps of 10 else take step of 1. I want to do this because limitation of my dataset, I have data for 1900,1910 till 1950 and then 1951,1952 so on for every year...

How can I change based on the year value? Is there a way?

Below is my current code

```
$( function() {
            $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
                orientation: "vertical",
                range: "min",
                min: 1900,
                max: 2015,
                step: 1,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#selected_year" ).val( ui.value );
                }
            });
            $( "#selected_year" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify step value of slider in change event handler:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
      //...    
      change: function( event, ui ) {
        var step = $(this).slider( "option", "step" );
        var newStep = step;
        if (ui.value < 1951) {
          newStep = 10;
        } else {
          newStep = 1;
        }
        if (newStep != step) {
          $(this).slider( "option", "step", newStep );
        }
      }      
    });
```